# Square-full Problem

Tags: number-theory

An integer is square-full if each of its prime factors occurs to at least the second power. Prove that there exists infinitely many pairs of consecutive square-full integers.

Comment: dosen't this imply that there are infinitely many pairs of consecutive perfect squares?

Comment: @Lelouch No. Odd powers are OK. Think 8 and 9.

Comment: oh so sorry !. I completely missed the 'at least' part. My bad

Comment: I'd rather call these numbers ""powerful", and leave "squareful" for those which are not squarefree.

Comment: The many votes to close surprise me. The question is interesting and hard enough so that someone new to number theory (and to this site) could ask it but have no way to start thinking about an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the solutions to the Pell equation

$$
x^2 - 2y^2 = 1.
$$

for which $y$ happens to be even. 
They start with the pairs $(x,y)  = (3,2), (17,12), \ldots$ leading to
$(9,8), (289,288), \ldots$

More generally, suppose $d$ is square free and there is a solution to the Pell equation
$$
x^2 - dy^2 = 1 \quad (*)
$$
for which $d$ divides $y$.  Then $(x^2, dy^2)$ is a pair of powerful numbers differing by $1$.

Once you have one such solution you can use it to find infinitely many.
To see why, suppose you have two solutions to $(*)$ for each of which $d$ divides $y$. Write them as  $(p, dq)$ and $(r,ds)$. Then  check that
$$
(pr + d^2q, dqr + dps) \quad (**)
$$
is a third solution with the same property. The two solutions you start with need not be different, so just one will get you infinitely many.

The construction in $(**)$ isn't magic. It comes from expanding the product
$$
(p + q \sqrt{d})(r + s \sqrt{d}) = ? + ?\sqrt{d}
$$

I suspect you can find such a starting pair for every square free $d$. For example, $(26, 15)$ works for $d=3$, yielding the pair $(676,675)$. That comes from the cube of the fundamental unit $2+\sqrt{3}$. Perhaps the $d$th power of the fundamental unit will always work. It does when $p$ is an odd prime since all the binomial coeffic1ents (except the first and last) are divisible by $p$.  I should check $d=6$ next ...

See http://www.zyvra.org/laforth/sqr2.htm

https://www.quora.com/We-know-that-the-square-root-of-2-is-an-irrational-number-but-what-is-the-nearest-fraction-that-can-be-equal-to-the-square-root-of-2-which-we-can-use-for-earthly-calculations

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html

Comment: Nice approach, I only miss a proof that we have infinite many solutions for $x^2-2y^2=1$ with an even $y$

Comment: @Peter That proof is well known to people who know Pell's equation or a little algebraic number theory. I've edited my answer to included a straightforward one that you can check with a little algebra.

Comment: I know the Pell-equations, not that I had doubt about the claim, but it was not obvious to me that $y$ is even infinite many times.